# Unhide div using ajax function

Tags: html, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I would like to unhide the hideEvent div when user is authenticated, Im able to redirect him to the home page but I'm still not able to unhide the div. Can someone help me please.

```
function loginUsers()
{
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'http://localhost/PHP/login.php',
data: $(this),
cache: false,
success: function(data){if(data[1] == "P"){window.location =     "http://localhost/index.html#homepg";$('#hideEvent').toggle();}else{alert("Wrong Email and Password!");}   
}});}`
```

Comment: If the post is working as it should then the problem is that you are not catching the div correctly.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça how can I catch it?

Comment: You should store if user is logged information in php SESSION variable, or    set cookies

Comment: play with jquery on chrome console, try to catch the correct div, and toggle it. And if it works, then the ajax call is being done before that div is in the DOM, i.e. the ajax call executes before that div is rendered.